# cap production deploy:check fails on Codeship.io - fails on git:check

Tags: capistrano, capistrano3

Curious if anyone can shed some light on why my deploy won't work on Codeship.io.  All goes well until git:check then it exits with a [non-helpful error](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/master/lib/capistrano/tasks/git.rake#L28).

Here's an overview of of what's happening:

1. Can manually deploy fine from local machines.
2. Set Codeship's public key in Github as a deploy key for the repo.
3. Placed Codeship's public key on server.

Using Codeship's interactive shell I can shell into the server, read/write files.  I also noticed that capistrano is able to write the git-ssh.sh into the server's /tmp directory.  I'm also able to use that file to [interact with the repo](https://gist.github.com/northband/7cb4ecb2e3c615988735).

However, every time I try a `cap production deploy:check` I get the following error: [Gist of Error](https://gist.github.com/northband/b0a8f0726b61f4fe7ab0).

Any help greatly appreciated as I've spent too much time debugging already.

Comment: Ever get this resolved?